# how to convert "["153","156","166","197"]" to ["153","156","166","197"]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

how to replace " before or after the [ ] in javascript?
**Please  Refer Attach Image for more reference.**

when i can ajax through JSP page then Controller  return list
"["153","156","166","197"]" in this format in JBOSS Server.

[image]

Comment: This is probably a case of the X/Y Problem. How are you inserting those values into your JS?

Comment: Since you use jQuery `$.ajax` try to set `dataType: 'json'` option.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `eval` but it's better to treat the string as JSON and parse it safely.

```
JSON.parse(result);
```

[image: console demo]

It's also possible your server can return a json content-type so the client can automatically parse the response.

Comment: backslashes are just to escape the quotes; otherwise you can't type the string in the console

Answer (score 0):

If your array is always correct, you can use `JSON.parse()`

```js
const result = '["1", "2", "3"]'
console.log('result is array?: ', Array.isArray(result))
const arrResult = JSON.parse(result);
console.log('arrResult is array?: ', Array.isArray(arrResult))
```

Have in mind though, that if your **result** is not parseable JS object you will get an exception. I recommend you to wrap your code into **try-catch** block in that case.